# CasperJS/PhantomJS how to keep old page open?

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I have form with some dynamic input that need to be filled. The problem is that to fill the form I need to visit another page to get data that depends on input on the previous page. So after I got a data and then backed to form, the form is already changed so I need to keep that form open while I getting a data for it. So question is how to make it?

Comment: Didn't get the entire scenario. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Ok, so you have a form that contains captcha (2+2/image), to solve it, you need to send request to script that can do it. How to send and get request while form is open?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with casper.back() and casper.forward() :
https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/master/tests/suites/casper/history.js
I suppose your previous form will be saved in the previous step.I hope so, try it.

Edit : 
getData(newPage) was an example of your own casper method, you could try something like that :

```
var password ="wtoc95a";

casper.getData = function (newPage, previousPageInputData) {
    //visit another page
    casper.open(newPage)
    //or casper.open(newPage+previousPageInputData) if the new page opened use the previous input
    .then(function() {
            //here you do what you want using "input" argument of the previous page
            //just return the data you need to fill the form
    });
    return dataNeeded;
};

And in your form : 
this.fill('form[id="signup_frm"]', { 
                nick_name: "pseudo", 
                e_mail: "mail",
                password: "password",
                password2: password,
                input : casper.getData(arg1,arg2)
```

http://docs.casperjs.org/en/1.1-beta2/extending.html

Comment: Nope. After using casper.back(); another form appears. I use casper.back(); twice.

Comment: Well, that just repeats an old step so. And if you try to call your own casper method to get the data and return it. In your scenario, when you fill the form, call casper.getData(newPage) to fill it.

Comment: I've edited, but i think you tried it : "Second, I put second instance in function and launch it when it's needed".

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create two casper instances. Where your first instance will have first page, and when required create another instance and get the data from it. Store data in casper's global scope.

Make waitFor until your variable value set @ first instance.

Comment: I tried few methods to create second instance. First, I tried create two instances right away and CasperJS/PhantomJS works with the last one only, ignoring the first. Second, I put second instance in function and launch it when it's needed, as result = not working. Can you show me working example, please ? –